# total sales of each product for each salesman who had sales on more than 1 product

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query for these three tables but I've failed.

I tried to conclude with having and group by statements, but I have errors in join structures

I wrote a query like this.

```
SELECT a.salesman_name, p.Product_name, Sum(t.quantity) FROM SALES t
inner join SALESMAN a on t.Salesman_id =a.Salesman_id 
inner join PRODUCT p on t.Product_id = p.Product_id
GROUP BY a.salesman_name, p.Product_name
HAVING Sum(t.quantity) > 1
```

but the query result should look like this:

```
+----------------+--------------+----------+
| SALESMAN_NAME  | PRODUCT_NAME | QUANTITY |
+----------------+--------------+----------+
| Ahmet Celik    | PRODUCT_A    |       25 |
| Ahmet Celik    | PRODUCT_D    |        5 |
| Ahmet Celik    | PRODUCT_E    |       10 |
| Coskun Metin   | PRODUCT_A    |       15 |
| Coskun Metin   | PRODUCT_B    |       10 |
| Ferhat Kaya    | PRODUCT_A    |        5 |
| Ferhat Kaya    | PRODUCT_C    |       12 |
| Ferhat Kaya    | PRODUCT_E    |        8 |
| Selim Albayrak | PRODUCT_C    |        5 |
| Selim Albayrak | PRODUCT_D    |        2 |
+----------------+--------------+----------+
```

I prepared the database in sqlfiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ba5ee/6

many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Skip p.Product_name in select list and group by. USe it in having instead.

Comment: update your question and add  your expected  result

Comment: explain the logic, what mean top sales for product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a quantity column in your fiddle. Based on that, the solution:

```
SELECT sm.salesman_name, p.product_name, min(quantity) as quantity
FROM Sales s
left outer JOIN Product p on p.product_id = s.product_id
left outer JOIN Salesman sm on sm.salesman_id = s.salesman_id
where quantity >= 1
Group By salesman_name, product_name
```

See: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ba5ee/20

Comment: Can I use inner join instead of left join?

Comment: Yes, you can. My quesion is this doesnt match your title description at all

Answer (score 0):

this code will help you. I tried. It success.

```
select distinct salesman.salesman_name, product.product_name, quantity
from sales
inner join salesman on salesman.salesman_id = sales.salesman_id
inner join product on product.product_id = sales.product_id
where salesman.salesman_name in (
select salesman.salesman_name
from sales
inner join salesman on salesman.salesman_id = sales.salesman_id
group by salesman.salesman_name
having count(salesman.salesman_name) > 1
)
and salesman.salesman_id not in(
select sales.salesman_id
from sales
group by sales.salesman_id, sales.product_id
having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: What does it do? It is helpful if it can explain a bit why this answer is better then the other answer.

Comment: Because Mahmut Tekin should not be on the list. He has sold the same product 2 times.  but when ı run sql query that another answer, I saw him. It's wrong. firstly we need to find person that sold more one products afterthan check person that sold more same product more 2 times and finally apply filtering.

Answer (score 0):

here the certain answer. no need to use inner join. ask if not understood

```
SELECT salesman.Salesman_name,
Product.Product_name,
sum(sales.Quantity)
FROM Salesman,Product,Sales where Salesman.Salesmanid=sales.Salesmanid
and Product.Productid=Sales.Productid and 1<(SELECT count(DISTINCT Productid) 
from sales
where Salesman.Salesmanid=Sales.Salesmanid)
group by Salesman_name,Product_name
```

Comment: This is an inner join, only other syntax used